# Open subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(M) \subseteq M^M$ where $M$ is an $L$-structure for a first order language $L$ and $M$ has discrete topology

Tags: general-topology, first-order-logic, model-theory, topological-groups

Let $L$ be a first order language and $M$ be an $L$-structure. For $ A \subseteq M $, let $\operatorname{Aut}_A (M)=\{f: M \to M$ is isomorphism $: f(a)=a,\forall a\in A\}$ and let $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ denote just the set of all isomorphisms of $M$ onto itself. Then $\operatorname{Aut}_A (M), \operatorname{Aut}(M)$ are all groups under usual function composition. Now equip $M$ with the discrete topology and equip $M^M$ with the product topology. Then $\operatorname{Aut}_A (M) \subseteq \operatorname{Aut}(M) \subseteq M^M$ . Moreover, I can prove that $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ is a topological group as a subspace of the product space $M^M$.

Then how to show that a subgroup $G$ of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ is open if and only if it contains $\operatorname{Aut}_A (M)$ for some finite subset $A \subseteq M$ ?

Comment: Is this related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673842/for-a-discrete-topological-space-x-is-permx-a-topological-group-as-a-subs somehow?

Comment: Can you see why $\operatorname{Aut}_A(M)$ is an open subgroup?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Let $\{f_\alpha\}$ be a net in the complement of $Aut _A (M)$ and converging to $f \in Aut (M)$ . Since $A$ is finite, some $a\in A$ is not fixed by $f_{\alpha}$ for infinitely many (does this make sense in general nets ?) $\alpha$. Then $f_{\alpha}(a)=f(a), \forall \alpha \ge \alpha _0$ and there is some $\alpha \ge \alpha_0$ such that $f_{\alpha}(a)\ne a$, hence $f(a)\ne a$, this $f$ is in the complement of $Aut_A (M)$ .... am I correct ?

Comment: You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Just show that $\{f\in M^M\mid\forall a\in A: f(a)=a\}$ is an open set in $M^M$ (almost directly from the definition), and then note that $\operatorname{Aut}_A(M)$ is just the intersection of that open set with the automorphism group.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Uhm I see ... but then again could you please say how to show the set that you are mentioning is open ?

Comment: Think about the nature of basic open sets in $M^M$, and the answer should reveal itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ok ... I think I can see now ... but how to prove the statement in my question here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) A subgroup of a topological group is open if and only if it contains an open neighborhood of the identity. Why? To show that $H\leq G$ is open it suffices to show it contains an open neighborhood of every point $x\in H$. If $e\in U\subseteq H$ and $U$ is open, then for any $x\in H$, $x\in Ux\subseteq H$ and $Ux$ is open, since multiplication by $x$ is a homeomorphism.

(2) A basic open set of $M^M$ has the form $U(\overline{a},\overline{b}) = \{f\colon M\to M\mid f(\overline{a}) = \overline{b}\}$, where $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ are tuples from $M$ of the same length. So a basic open set in the subspace $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ has the form $U(\overline{a},\overline{b})\cap \mathrm{Aut}(M) = \{f\colon M\to M\mid f\text{ is an automorphism, and }f(\overline{a}) = \overline{b}\}$. Now $H\leq \mathrm{Aut}(M)$ is an open subgroup if and only if it contains a *basic* open neighborhood of the identity. And if $\text{id}_M\in U(\overline{a},\overline{b})$, then $\overline{a} = \mathrm{id}_M(\overline{a}) = \overline{b}$. So such a basic open neighborhood has the form $U(\overline{a},\overline{a}) \cap \mathrm{Aut}(M) = \mathrm{Aut}_A(M)$, where $A$ is the set enumerated by the tuple $\overline{a}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why basic open sets are of the form $\{f :M \to M: f(\bar a)=\bar b \}$ ... that is the only thing I'm having difficulty in understanding . Thanks

Comment: Ok, walking through this very slowly: The discrete topology on $M$ has a basis consisting of the singletons. To get a basis for the product topology on $M^M$, you take the intersection of finitely many preimages of basic opens in different coordinates. A coordinate is indexed by some $a$ in $M$, and a basic open set in that coordinate is a singleton $b$ in $M$. So the elements of $M^M$ in the preimage of this open set are those which have value $b$ in the $a$ coordinate, equivalently functions $M\to M$ with $f(a)=b$. Now if you take an intersection of finitely many such sets, what do you get?

Comment: Thank you, thanks a lot